# Write a text that would be the source code (Java)

Tags: java

the task is:

"Write a complete Java program called Date whose output is the text that would be the source code of a Java program that prints "Introduction to Java Programming!" as its output."

Dont I only have to write a single statement with "System.out.println("Introduction to Java Programming!");" ?

Or they want something else from me?

Thank you for help!

Comment: You need a `main()` and all the other essentials of a simple Java program as well.

Comment: That would output `Introduction to Java Programming!`, which is certainly not a valid Java program.

Comment: You need to have a Class, main method, and this statement together.

Comment: Half a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: public class Data {
    public static void main (String []args){
        System.out.println("In....Programming!");
    }
}

Thats it?

Comment: This task seems to easy for me but maybe it is how it seems like^^

Comment: I'd totally do it the `System.out.println("...");` way, and also with this library and show off both https://github.com/square/javapoet :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is, to write a program in Java that itself spits out Java code, that, when compiled would spit out that sentence.

something like

```
 main()
 {
    System.out.prinln("main () { System.out.println(\"....
```

I don't know who's assigning such homework, but that's the most useless stuff I ever heard and doesn't get you anywhere in learning Java...

Comment: ok thanks then it is as easy as it seems like...that was confusing me you know, thank you.

Comment: ahhhhh wait now i understand :D

Comment: That's just one of the ways to try to convince people not to become programmers ;) Only the most twisted people find enjoyment from things like that (or programming golf).

Comment: Well I didnt know what a "source code" is, now I know it, so it wasnt so useless for me!

Comment: Jo habs jetzt, danke. Der Quellcode ist einfach das, was man selber zB in Eclipse "eintippt", das wusste ich vorher nicht. :)

Comment: One of my professors tried to shove recursion down my throat, when iteration was obviously better choice. So I slammed the door on him. Needless to say, in the end I quit and decided to learn coding on my own. if you want to be a programmer, don't go to University.

Comment: @TheLaw Right. I've done Fortran, Prolog. tcl/Tk, Perl, PHP, Java, ECMA, ... w/o ever having any lesson. Just good books.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a surrounding class around your statement.

```
System.out.println("Introduction to Java Programming!");
```

And some specific method, starting with the character `m`, to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into `StringBuilder` class to keep your sanity. But I wonder who assigns such stupid assignment. Pointless exercise, really.